# Center UIButton text for floating action button like Inbox app

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

```
floatingButton = UIButton(x: blocx, y:blocy, width: imageSize, height: imageSize, target: self, action: "clickedFloatingButton")
floatingButton!.backgroundColor = CozyColors.StatCardSkip
floatingButton!.layer.cornerRadius = floatingButton!.frame.size.width / 2
floatingButton!.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
floatingButton!.setTitleColor(CozyColors.ThemeWhite, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
floatingButton!.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: CozyStyles.ThemeFontName, size: imageSize*2/3)
view.addSubview(floatingButton!)
```

Here is the result:

[image: inbox app floating button action]

As you can see the plus button is not aligned properly to the center. How can I put it right in the middle without adding a UILabel as a subview?

Comment: I'm afraid, you couldn't

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
    var floatingButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50))
    floatingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    floatingButton.layer.cornerRadius = floatingButton.frame.size.width / 2
    floatingButton.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    floatingButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    floatingButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: floatingButton.titleLabel!.font.familyName , size: 50)
    floatingButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, 0, 0, 0)
    view.addSubview(floatingButton)
```

Comment: what to do if the size is dynamic and the edgeinset value is going to be dynamic?

Comment: @Esq you have to count top edge dynamically as per size. else you can use the `UIBezierPath` as suggested by #DharmeshKheni

Answer (score 2):

You set your Title Edge Inset as below. Change its value and set title middle.

```
floatingButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-24, 0, 0, 0);
```

according below function change value.

```
func UIEdgeInsetsMake(top: CGFloat, left: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

Comment: what to do if the size is dynamic and the edgeinset value is going to be dynamic?

Comment: The Title Top Space Depending on FontSize and Height, So Have to Change according to its.

Answer (score 2):

Well,I think a easier way is just set a background image for it

```
    floatingButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "icon.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

You can apply the transform or find a similar image from google

[image]

And the background image is here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw your button with `UIBezierPath` and here is your code:

```
import UIKit

class PushButtonView: UIButton {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        path.fill()

        //set up the width and height variables
        //for the horizontal stroke
        let plusHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
        let plusWidth: CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * 0.6

        //create the path
        var plusPath = UIBezierPath()

        //set the path's line width to the height of the stroke
        plusPath.lineWidth = plusHeight

        //move the initial point of the path
        //to the start of the horizontal stroke
        plusPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 - plusWidth/2 + 0.5, y:bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

        //add a point to the path at the end of the stroke
        plusPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 + plusWidth/2 + 0.5, y:bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

        //Vertical Line

        //move to the start of the vertical stroke
        plusPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 + 0.5, y:bounds.height/2 - plusWidth/2 + 0.5))

        //add the end point to the vertical stroke
        plusPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 + 0.5, y:bounds.height/2 + plusWidth/2 + 0.5))

        //set the stroke color
        UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

        //draw the stroke
        plusPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

You can refer [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Draw-Button) sample project for more Info. And you can modify it as per your need.

Hope It will help you.